# How can I create different screen size image in android

Tags: android

I am new to android I would like to ask some help if there is an application that will create automatically different screen size image for my app. ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the [`screens_support documentation`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html), there you'll find the answer to your question.

For example this is the differents types of `Images` that you can add on your project.

> A set of six generalized densities:
>
> - ldpi (low) ~120dpi
> - mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
> - hdpi (high) ~240dpi
> - xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
> - xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Also it's important to know  :

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>
> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>
> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Also you can use a "tool" to put your images with those size it's called : [`AndroidAssetStudio`](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

Also take a look at this [post](http://tools.android.com/recent/assetstudiointegration) and this [one](http://envyandroid.com/easiest-way-to-create-android-icons/) it might help you.

Answer (score 3):

The Android Asset Studio (https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio) is a great tool you can use.